# MATLAB date to number

Tags: matlab, date, type-conversion

I am wondering if it is possible to change a date in matlab to a sting in the following format:

`'18-12-2014'` to `'18122014'`

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Minor misuse of date formatting functions:

```
output = datestr(datenum('18-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ddmmyyyy');
```

Various indexing methods:

```
s = '18-12-2014';
s(strfind(s,'-')) = [];

s = '18-12-2014'
s = s([1:2,4:5,7:end]);
```

Comment: Or just `s(s=='-') = [];`

Comment: @LuisMendo you are correct, but I think `datestr` `datenum` solution is more instructive and more general.